# DataGridView sort programmatically, case sensitive

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, vb6

I'm working on a project converting VB6 applications to VB.NET. It's on the first step, having gone through conversion through Visual Basic 2008. I'm replacing FlexGrids with DataGridViews and have come up against some problems I'm having a really hard time finding the answer to.

One problem is that the sorting on the FlexGrid had many options. The only options I see with DataGridView are:

```
System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending
```

I need case sensitive sorting. I've looked everywhere and haven't found what I need. It was even hard finding the code above. Any help is very appreciated.

Edit: The grid is filled programmatically.

Comment: Where is the data?  Was it added manually or is it in a datasource?

Comment: Sorry, it's added manually. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Are you talking about sorting the data when it is loaded or changing the sort criteria when clicking on a column header?

Comment: When it's loaded. Sorting is disabled otherwise.

Comment: It's the last thing that's done after the data is loaded.

Comment: Maybe something like this where you create your own SortCompare Event ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd seen that and I didn't think it applied since my grid doesn't have an ID column. I did try this but I don't see how I can make it do sorting case sensitive, unless I do a loop and check each character against the other, but that seems excessive. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are manually filling the grid, then `ListSortDirection.Ascending` should be all you need.

For example, given the following list of `Example` items (in *any* order):

```
Dim examples = New List(Of Example)() From { _
    New Example() With { _
        Key .Bar = "Abcd", _
        Key .Foo = "3" _
    }, _
    New Example() With { _
        Key .Bar = "ABcd", _
        Key .Foo = "4" _
    }, _
    New Example() With { _
        Key .Bar = "aBcd", _
        Key .Foo = "2" _
    }, _
    New Example() With { _
        Key .Bar = "abcd", _
        Key .Foo = "1" _
    } _
}
```

With the following setup:

```
Dim col1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
Dim col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

col1.Name = "Foo"
col2.Name = "Bar"

col1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
col2.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic

Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1)
Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col2)

For Each example As Example In examples
    Me.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(example.Foo, example.Bar)
Next

Me.dataGridView1.Sort(col2, ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

You should always see the results as:

[image: DataGridView ascended sort for "Bar" column]

Comment: Thank you, I had not been using it correctly. This does the trick.